# When printing  in terminal, additional REPLACEMENT CHARACTER “�” (U+FFFD) appears

Tags: python, unicode, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm seeing weird extra glyphs while printing unicode

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Dec  5 2018, 15:01:38)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("\N{snake}")
�
```

This is what it looks like in [the terminal](https://github.com/felixse/FluentTerminal):

[image: cap]

The unwanted character appears to be [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FFFD), ord 0xfffd.

```
>>> import locale, sys, os
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
>>> os.environ["LANG"]
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
```

What can cause that and how to fix it? Any other details you'd like provided let me know in comments and I'll edit them in.

Comment: code works correctly on Linux Mint with standard terminal but not in xterm (it shows only �) . Maybe problem is only your terminal (some settings), not Python.

Comment: That is a non-BMP code point (U+1F40D) and some terminals don't handle them properly.  What is the operating environment?

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yep, same with all emoji codepoints, just picked the snake as an example. What do you mean by operating environment? It's RHEL on WSL running in FluentTerminal. This is [IUS](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-x86_64/python36u-3.6.7-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm.html) python36u.